# C#: How to add formula to Excel through C# Code. Getting invalid Formula error

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Column 'I' have To date

Column 'H' have From date

I want to calculate difference between two date and store it in column 'J'.

Formula to do this is "=DATEDIF(I18,H18,"d")"

I am getting below error if i execute below code.

Error: Invalid formula.
ArgumentException was unhandled by user code.

```
    private void FillExcelCellFormula(IRange cell, int row, int column, object content)
    {
        string row1 = "I" + Convert.ToString(row);
        string row2 = "H" + Convert.ToString(row);
        string dquote = @"""d""";
        string daysFormula = "=DATEDIF(" + row1 + "," + row2 + "," + dquote + ")";

        cell.FormulaR1C1 = daysFormula;
    }
```

Formula value getting poppulated in daysFormula = "=DATEDIF(I18,H18,\"d\")"

Although i am not sure if the '\' is the reason behind the error.

Even a simple sum function is not working. I replaced the formula to a simpler formula like,

string daysFormula = "=SUM(A18:B18)";
yet i am getting same error.

Do i have to call for any library?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that a VBA function? I can't find it in my list of built-in functions.

Comment: @Ron Beyer   No. Asp.net C#

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the To & From dates.

What format are they stored in, in your Excel file ?

If they are stored as string, this might cause the error.  Dates need to be stored as integers, with styling applying to *display them* as dates.

**Update**

Btw, dumb question:  What happens if you use `Formula` rather than `FormulaR1C1`:

```
cell.Formula = daysFormula;
```

Comment: Even a simple sum function is not working. I replaced the formula to a simpler formula like,

string daysFormula = "=SUM(A18:B18)"; yet i am getting same error.

Comment: @rkm is the cell formatted as text, general or something more specific?